# VDebug stopped working arbitrarily

Tags: php, xdebug, vim-plugin

I have been having this problem sporadically with both DBGPavim and VDebug. It might be fairly localized but then again, it has a likelihood of having someone else experience this as well.

I have pathogen setup and vdebug cloned in my /bundle folder inside /vim. The plugin was working fine but now it has arbitrarily stopped working. Basically I hit F5 and get the following message:

**"Waiting for a connection (Ctrl-C to cancel, this message will self-destruct in  20  seconds...)"**

I navigate to the URL and hit F5 only to get the page load without hitting the debugger breakpoint, eventually a message relays itself on the terminal file:

**No Connection was made**

I have an Ubuntu setup and XDebug is installed @:

```
 /etc/php5/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

with the following settings:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php5/20090626/xdebug.so
xdebug.profiler_append = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable = 0
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = 1
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 4024
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 30
```

Tried following the troubleshoot of VDebug, but everything seems set correctly. It has been installed for PHP, vim --version shows that VDebug is being loaded and it is listening to the same port as xdebug (9000).

Are there any other points of conflict I should be checking upon ?

Comment: try `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` instead of `xdebug.remote_host = localhost` and if it works then localhost is not recognized in your host file